# Pipeline fails when using Nextflow Tower/Google Cloud Batch

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nextflow

I am attempting to run the simple https://github.com/nextflow-io/hello pipeline using **Nextflow Tower + Google Cloud Batch**. I see the

> volume.mount_options field is invalid.

but have no idea where that comes from. Definitely not in the pipeline files. Any idea on how to address this?

I have attached the log file:

```
tee: /.nextflow/cache/nf-4LA57uRo58tGDX.txt: No such file or directory
N E X T F L O W  ~  version 23.08.1-edge
Pulling nextflow-io/hello ...
 downloaded from https://github.com/nextflow-io/hello.git
Launching `https://github.com/nextflow-io/hello` [ecstatic_lorenz] DSL2 - revision: 1d71f857bb [master]
Monitor the execution with Nextflow Tower using this URL: https://tower.nf/user/qup9/watch/4LA57uRo58tGDX
ERROR ~ Error executing process > 'sayHello (2)'
Caused by:
  INVALID_ARGUMENT: volume.mount_options field is invalid. mount_option -o rw,allow_other has potential shell injection, please check again.
 -- Check '/.nextflow/cache/nf-4LA57uRo58tGDX.log' file for details
Saving cache: .nextflow/cache/69ddfddf-79cd-467e-b112-b4054861bd15 => gs://nf-tower-6897ad32-d3d4-xxxx-ade1-97d25c0e680c/scratch/4LA57uRo58tGDX/.nextflow/cache/69ddfddf-79cd-467e-b112-b4054861bd15
```

Comment: can you try removing the `allow_other` option from your mount options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download patch which solves the issue using batch `nextflow plugin install nf-google@1.7.3-patch1`
2. Ensure nextflow pipeline is using this patch version by pinning this version on nextflow.config file with:

```
plugins {
    id 'nf-validation'
    id 'nf-google@1.7.3-patch1'
}
```

Comment: that worked; now how do I get NExtflow-Tower to actually use my Container ?